# Finding words in brackets that contain a single char using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find all words which are enclosed in double brackets and contain a bracket in the middle of the word, I am using Java.

I have this so far but its not quite working.

```
\\[\\[[\\[|\\]]\\]\\]
```

Any suggestions?

For this sample input `"hello [[wo[orld]]"`, I'd like to find `"[[wo[orld]]"`.

Comment: Could you give examples of what you're trying to find? Sample inputs and outputs would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
String str = "hello [[wo[orld]]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[[^\\[\\]]*[\\[\\]][^\\[\\]]*\\]\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

**Output:**

```
[[wo[orld]]
```

---

**Pattern breakdown:**

- `\[\[`          -- Two initial `[[` (you got that right already!)
- `[^\[\]]*`  -- Something else than `[` and `]` zero or more times
- `[\[\]]`       -- The "middle" bracket symbol
- `[^\[\]]*`  -- Something else than `[` and `]` zero or more times
- `\]\]`          -- Two closing `]]` (that one you figured out as well)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture what's in the double brackets and if you don't care whether or not there are other non-bracket characters around the single bracket, try:

`(\[\[[^\[\]]*\[[^\[\]]*\]\])`

Otherwise, if there must be at least one non-bracket character around the innermost bracket, change the asterisks to plusses, aka:

`(\[\[[^\[\]]+\[[^\[\]]+\]\])`

Answer (score -2):

The term bracket is a bit overloaded but I assume you are trying to match strings of the form:

[[some[thing]]

```
String sampleString = "[[some[thing]]";
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\[\\[.*\\[.*\\]\\]", sampleString)); //true
```

Pattern.matches() is a static method that returns true for a match, otherwise false

Comment: `[]` = brackets, `{}` = braces, `()` = parenthesis: there is nothing confusing about this in the software world, it has always been like this. Also this pattern doesn't meet the requirements `.*` would match   `[` or `]` as well you have to exclude them.

Comment: To be fair, I have heard of `{}` referred to as "curly brackets".  However, an unqualified "brackets" always means `[]`.

Comment: `<` = angle brackets, `[` = square brackets, `{` are occasionally referred to as curly brackets. The original posting of this question didn't provide an example so I stated my assumption.

Comment: This answer fails on the input data anyway, `.*` will match `[` or `]` you have to specifically exclude them from the match as the correct answers do.